# Using Mercurial with Cygwin?

Tags: mercurial, cygwin

We've been trying to use Mercurial with Cygwin (on Windows) but run into an error as Cygwin uses forward slashes and Mercurial seems to require backslashes.  Is there a workaround?

Example of issue:

```
hg status 
M src\myfile.java

hg ci src\myfile.java   <-- Error: abort: srcmyfile.java: The system cannot find the file specified
```

??

Comment: Have you tried installing Mercurial inside cygwin rather than trying to use the Windows Mercurial? Presumably Mercurial would behave in a more unix-y way if it is running under Python compiled for cygwin.

Comment: @joeforker, that's not a bad suggestion except if you use the unix version at all for a given repository, you have to *only* use the unix version, or you will get weird errors because of the path differences.  That precludes using tools like IDE integration or tortoisehg to supplement your cygwin CLI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have such a problem because I use two Mercurials:

- mercurial bundled with [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) for use in windows cmd shell (usually I don't use it directly but it's used by TortoiseHG GUI tools).
- cygwin's mercurial which I can use in cygwin.

You can safely use both of them because both versions store version history in the same `.hg` folder. Mercurial stores info about paths in `.hg` folder is some OS-independent way.

To be safe use the same version for both Mercurials.

Comment: Interesting I will try.  In the comments to the question @Karl Bielefeldt indicates there might be an issue with this approach.  But it sounds like you haven't encountered any such issues..

Comment: Cygwin's Mercurial works well but I have run into a few annoying little issues..   but this is the only solution I've found that comes close to being workable..

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your .hgrc:

```
[ui]
slash = true
```

Now TortoiseHg will use proper slashes too:

```
C:> hg status
M src/myfile.java
```

Comment: This makes it so much easier to copy and paste `hg status` results! This is because (via a mingw/cygwin shell) there is already conversion of `/` to `\ ` when calling a command, however using a bare `\ ` in bash will go 'vomit'

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem for bzr by using a shell script that converts the slashes using the cygpath command.  It may require some tweaking for your needs, but here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
COMMAND="/c/Python27/python.exe c:\\\\Python27\\\\Scripts\\\\bzr"
for i in "$@"
do
    COMMAND+=" "
    if [[ "$i" =~ ^- || "$i" =~ // ]]
    then
        COMMAND+="$i"
    else
        COMMAND+=$(cygpath -m "$i" | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
    fi
done
eval $COMMAND
```

It cycles through all the command line arguments.  If it starts with a minus sign (bzr option), it just appends the argument as is.  Otherwise, it runs it through cygpath and escapes all the spaces.  I don't remember what the `"$i" =~ //` is for.  It doesn't match up what I thought it was.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the `"$i" =~ //` was a simple way of detecting a URL so it won't get converted to a windows path.  It has worked for me, but there are more robust ways to do it if you're so inclined.

Answer (score 0):

[Ian Lewis](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/using-mercurial-on-windows-with-cygwin) suggests:

> Uninstall the cygwin mercurial package and put TortoiseHG's path in my PATH environment variable (well it was already there) and everything's dandy. TortoiseHG just magically works on windows (though mercurial repos on the windows network are sloooooow). It's nice to be able to just type 'hg push' and have it work as well as "hg merge" the same way I do at home on my linux machine ("hg view" is "hgtk log" though).

Which amounts to "don't use cygwin's hg if your going to also use Tortoise HG", which seems like the best solution to me.